# Unity: GetComponent results in nullreference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene that contains a nested prefab.
The nested prefab contains multiple barrel prefabs (image below)

These barrel prefabs have components: a transform, animation, mesh filter and a  mesh renderer

The problem is that i can't find the mesh filter & mesh renderer by code. Everything works fine in the Unity player! But when i build for pc i get a nullreference on `gobj.getComponent, but only on the objects that have the "barrel" tag, (oil works fine and has the same components):

```
private void EvaluateAll() //gets called from awake
{
    EvaluateDissolve();
    EvaluateFish();
    EvaluateFloor();
    EvaluateFogCol();
    EvaluateFogDens();
    EvaluatePlants();
    EvaluateRocks();
}

private void EvaluateDissolve()
{
        foreach (GameObject gobj in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("oil"))
        {
            gobj.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.SetFloat("_SliceAmount",m_dissolveFactor + 0.2f);
        }

        foreach (GameObject gobj in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("barrel"))
        {
            gobj.GetComponent<Renderer().sharedMaterial.SetFloat("_SliceAmount",m_dissolveFactor);
        }
}
```

I tried logging all the components of my barrel objects, it logs only the animation and transform components, for some reason the mesh renderer and mesh filter are not logged (this code is called from the awake function):

```
foreach (GameObject gobj in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("barrel"))
{
            Debug.Log("is object active? " + gobj.activeInHierarchy.ToString());
            Debug.Log("barrel scene: " + gobj.scene.name.ToString());
            Debug.Log("asking components of barrel, is barrel null?" + (gobj == null).ToString());

            Component[] components = gobj.GetComponents(typeof(Component));
            foreach (Component comp in components)
            {
                Debug.Log(comp.GetType().ToString());
            }
            gobj.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.SetFloat("_SliceAmount",m_dissolveFactor);
 }
```

[image: scene structure]

[image]

Comment: *"i get a nullreference on barrel.getComponent<Renderer>"* .....There is no `i get a nullreference on barrel.getComponent<Renderer>` in your code. Since we don't have access to your scene objects, it would be good to point out where exactly the error is occurring.

Comment: i added some info to point out where exactly the error is occuring

Comment: Still don't know. I will give an advice on how to figure out what's causing this easily. If you are sure the problem is from here: `gobj.GetComponent<Renderer()` then Add a simple `Text` component to the middle of your screen. Modify this text depending if it is null or not. If `gobj.GetComponent<Renderer()` is null, print it then use `break` to break out of the loop. You can also pint the name of the GameObject to the `Text` component with `yourUIText.text = gobj.name;` Reply back to me if you find anything

Comment: I'm sure the renderer component is null because its not printed in my logs, i log everything and check these out in the builds with a tool called reporter. I also explicitly checked if getComponent<Renderer>() == null and printed a log to tell me that its null

Comment: Ok, now print the name of the GameObject that is null like i said above and tell me what it is.

Comment: gobj.GetComponent<Renderer() is null, it prints null on the screen...

Comment: No, please see my two comments above. I asked you to print `gobj.name` and tell me the name of the Object with null Renderer. then break out of the loop. `if (gobj.GetComponent<Renderer>() == null){Debug.Log(gobj.name); break;}` You can also use `yourUIText.text = gobj.name`.  So, what's the name?

Comment: it says Fish1 lol what the actual fuck, my fish don't have the barrel tag ...

Comment: any idea how this is possible ? I also printed the tag and its says "barrel", none of my fish objects have that tag, this is really weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetComponent` will never return null unless the component is not attached to that Object or the component is destroyed.

Your `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("oil")` or `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("barrel")` is finding a GameObject with the "oil" or "barrel" tag respectively.

After this, `GetComponent<Renderer()` is used in a loop to access each `Renderer` returned by `FindGameObjectsWithTag`. According to your, it returns null sometimes and the the loop that returns null points to a GameObject called *"Fish1"*.

The problem is that you have mistakenly changed the tag of Fish1 to either "oil" or "barrel". `FindGameObjectsWithTag` will then pick it up and try to check for its Renderer which is null.

**Change the *"Fish1"* tag to Untagged** so that `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("oil")` and `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("barrel")` won't find it.

Now, if you really meant to have *"Fish1"* to have "oil" or "barrel" tag then you must make sure that a `MeshRender` is attached to it.

**Note**:

There is a search bar in the Editor, use that to search for *"Fish1"* GameObjects in the scene and change the tag.

Also, make sure that you are not instantiating any GameObject named "*"Fish1"* with "oil" or "barrel" tag. This is very important. It's not magic. `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` is returning it because it exist in the scene.

Comment: my fish don't have the barrel tag i swear, wtf

Comment: i resetted the tag, even though it wasn't barrel, and it solved my problem

Comment: Maybe that's cache/save problem in the Editor but I believe you changed the tag in the paste and changed it back but Unity did not recognize that change. Not to mention that "Fish1" looks like a prefab to me since it is colored blue so I believe that you did not apply the changes made to it.

Comment: Anyway thank you very much i wasted alot of time to find the problem

Comment: It's not a time wasted as long as you learned something new like printing the object name and tag. I guarantee you will be able to solve most of your other null issues. You are welcome!

Comment: its pretty wasted lol i knew that i could ask the name i just never imagined that the findcomponentwithTag would give wong results. The core of the problem is in the asset that contains the tags (TagManager.asset). Its corrupt